# Line in Realtek high definition audio not plugged in

Tags: audio, microphone, recording

[image]

From the Control Panel -> Sound -> Recording I have this :
Line in Realtek Hight Definition Audio Not plugged in
Wich annoy me a lot, I wish it to be perfect.
I don't understand that, I what is wrong with it. How can I plug it in?

Thanks for help.

Addtionnal information:

- I'm using windows 10
- My microphone is pluggued at the back
- I use a MG102C audio Mixer (Yamaha) with a lot of cables.
- I can record something using my microphone
- I have "hum" ground loop noise, with monitor speaker/microphone, I bought some Audio Noise Filter Ground Loop Isolator Suppressor at ebay to try to solve this other issue.
- My computer is brand new, I have build it myself from parts bought on the internet, no external sound card.
- My motherboard: ASUS X99-DELUXE II (https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Motherboards/X99-DELUXE-II/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line in is something different, not meant for microphones. It's completely normal. It is used to say connect a MP3 player into the computer for whatever purpose you may need it for. Some motherboards don't even have them, but your motherboard appears to, and can be seen as the blue input in the back. More info is avaliable on Microsoft's site on this link: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/connect-audio-device#1TC=windows-7
I hope I helped, have a great day!

Comment: I knew it actually, I just didn't make the link between the ideas. Thanks for your help. I've plugged an rca to 1/8 cable from my sound mixer and it states ready instead of Not plugged.